# How can I get data after passing parameter of SQL Server procedure in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to get data from a SQL Server database using a procedure passing some parameters. Is this the right way to do this? The code shown here is not working. Is there any way to get data ?

I want to call

**Controller:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public ReportController(IConfiguration configuration, DatabaseContext context)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _context = context;
    }

    [Route("AllCollectionReport")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CollectionReport()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string imsConn = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:IMSConnection"];

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(imsConn))
        {
            string query = "KK_SP_VIEWREPO"; //<-- Here is the procedure

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok(dt);
    }
}
```

SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE KK_SP_VIEWREPO
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM KK_SalesEntry
END
```

This is the error what I got after get calling the method in Postman - is anything wrong with this code?

```
Get: https://localhost:44372/api/Report/AllCollectionReport
```

> Error: System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.
>
> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32 maxDepth)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**HEADERS**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:44372
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5
Postman-Token: d65e0dd3-3c9d-4066-ba8f-db7940509c60
```

Help me..  :-(

Comment: 405 status code and your action attribute indicate that you need to use GET instead of POST

Comment: I have updated my error msg. What the wrong with this code?? Any idea @YegorAndrosov

Comment: you cant return data table since it is not serializable, you need to map it to a custom object first

Comment: How can i do it ? Help me with some code .. I am beginner :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return DataTable. It is not serializable. You can return Strongly Typed object.

something like this may help

```
    List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                 objList.Add(new { 
                     UserId = reader[0].ToString()
                     UserName = raeder[1].ToString()
                 });
            }
        }
    }

    return objList;
```